# How to find a sub-graph within a graph

Tags: gremlin

I want to select a sub-graph (not just a path) within a graph. As an example, in the context of the "modern" Tinkerpop graph (see image below) I'm trying to select the whole graph.

The first query `g.V(6).out('created').has('name', 'lop').both('created').or(__.has("age", 29), __.has("name", "josh")).path()` gets me almost there - two paths from Peter to Josh and Marko. I just need to extend the path to include Ripple and Vadas.

The second query `g.V(6).out('created').has('name', 'lop').both('created').or(__.has("age", 29), __.has("name", "josh")).V().or(__.has("name", "ripple"), __.has("name", "vadas")).path()` unexpectedly yields four paths, not two. I would expect the query result to be

```
==>[v[6],v[3],v[1],v[2]]
==>[v[6],v[3],v[4],v[5]]
```

Instead I get

```
==>[v[6],v[3],v[1],v[2]]
==>[v[6],v[3],v[1],v[5]]
==>[v[6],v[3],v[4],v[2]]
==>[v[6],v[3],v[4],v[5]]
```

Here's the whole thing:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
gremlin> g.V(6).out('created').has('name', 'lop').both('created').or(__.has("age", 29), __.has("name", "josh")).path()
==>[v[6],v[3],v[1]]
==>[v[6],v[3],v[4]]
gremlin> g.V(6).out('created').has('name', 'lop').both('created').or(__.has("age", 29), __.has("name", "josh")).V().or(__.has("name", "ripple"), __.has("name", "vadas")).path()
==>[v[6],v[3],v[1],v[2]]
==>[v[6],v[3],v[1],v[5]]
==>[v[6],v[3],v[4],v[2]]
==>[v[6],v[3],v[4],v[5]]
```

Note that I'm trying to do this with version 2.6.0. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason not to use subgraph() step in this case? http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#subgraph-step

Comment: Yes, I'm using gremlin 2.6.0 :-) But just for interest's sake, how would you use `subGraph()` in this case?

Answer (score 4):

In TinkerPop 3.x, I would use [subgraph()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#subgraph-step)-step. It produces an edge-induced subgraph, meaning it collects edges that you traverse into a new graph along with the adjacent vertices that they connect.

Your question states that you are "trying to select the whole graph." If that's the case, then just do:

```
gremlin> sg = g.E().subgraph('sg').cap('sg').next().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
```

It iterates all the edges in the graph and pushes them into a new graph, labelled "sg", that we `cap()` out at the end into a new `Graph` instance.

More likely, you need to filter parts of a graph into your subgraph, so just write your traversal and collect the edges you have Gremlin walk over:

```
gremlin> sg = g.V().has('name','marko').outE('knows').subgraph('sg').inV().outE('created').subgraph('sg').cap('sg').next().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:5 edges:4], standard]
```

Comment: sorry - no....i don't remember any aspect of how 2.x works. we stopped maintaining it so long ago....